# IDE for Jquery development

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ide, jquery-widgets

What do you suggest for JQuery development IDE. Is there something similar to Eclipse for java, so I can run/debug my application in it?

Im getting a lot of work based on JQuery Widget and JQuery UI.

I'm working on Fedora.

Comment: Text editor + Chrome developer tools

Comment: Press F12 in any modern browser and you can debug JS/jQuery...

Comment: Your local files in the browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: no i use CDN for jquery files. the rest are inline scripts

Comment: @Shomz - [**My Workflow: Never having to leave DevTools**](http://remysharp.com/2012/12/21/my-workflow-never-having-to-leave-devtools/).

Comment: You can still use CDN links in your local HTML file.  I don't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using netbeans. It has quite a good JS Editor and works sometimes well with jQuery but has not all functions integrated and can't suggest the params right - but i don't know any IDE who can do this

For editing use debugger tools in modern browsers like chrome ;)